# How to have two NIC in ubuntu server and not affecting dns?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

In my Ubuntu server 16.04 I have this file:  /etc/network/interfaces

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

#auto eth1
#iface eth1 inet static
#    address 10.0.0.41
#    netmask 255.255.255.0
#    network 10.0.0.0
#    broadcast 10.0.0.255
#    gateway 10.0.0.1
```

The eth0 is linked to dsl, if I uncomment the eth1 section to enable second NIC card, I can't ping remote server like yahoo.com:

```
ping yahoo.com
PING yahoo.com (98.138.253.109) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.41 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.41 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.41 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution: remove the gateway 10.0.0.1